# Preview looks cleaner when changing page

Tags: macos, pdf, preview

I was reading a pdf document in full screen mode with preview (MBP mid-2009 with El Capitan) and I've noticed something wired : the document is prettier right when I'm scrolling pages.

[image: Clean lines]

[image: Blurry lines]

Is this a bug that I need to get fixed or a feature I can understand/control so that the rendering is sharp always?